# access of elements within coxph object

Tags: r

If I have R data like:

```
> European204cad.prs.basic$coefficients
age_diabetes_diagnosis                    Sex                 SCOREZ 
            0.05807447             0.27131656             0.33191227 
                  PCA1                   PCA2 
           32.81616512           -21.6415698
```

How can I access `SCOREZ` programmatically?

I tried

```
> European204cad.prs.basic$coefficients$SCOREZ
Error in European204cad.prs.basic$coefficients$SCOREZ : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

But as you can see, it's wrong

I've tried other potential splits (maybe "element access" is better?), like `@`, or `[` but none work.

I don't know the correct search terms.

How can I access the value of 0.3319 programmatically?

Comment: Try `coefficients(European204cad.prs.basic)["SCOREZ"]`

Comment: or perhaps `European204cad.prs.basic$coefficients["SCOREZ"]`, noting that since it is not a `data.frame` nor `list`, the `$`-accessor does not work. Being a named vector, `[`-indexing is preferred.

Comment: @r2evans-GONAVYBEATARMY if you write your answer, I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use

```r
European204cad.prs.basic$coefficients["SCOREZ"]
```

The `$`-accessor works with `data.frame`s and `list`s, but the coefficients are a named-vector, e.g., `c(a=1, b=2)`. For that format, you need the `[`-accessor only. (Informative reading about `$`, `[`, and `[[`: [The difference between bracket [ ] and double bracket [[ ]] for accessing the elements of a list or dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/3358272)).